# Google API v2 location.getLatitude() return nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, google-maps-android-api-2

Ok so the problem is this, when I use the code below, using ACCURACY_COARSE, everything works except the location is NOT accurate to where I am.

```
// Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

// Getting LocationManager object from System Service
// LOCATION_SERVICE
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Getting the name of the best provider
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

// Getting Current Location
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

if (location != null) {
    onLocationChanged(location);
}

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

// Get current location Latitude and Longitude
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
```

But when i use this code i get a nullpointerexception from location.getLatitude();

```
// Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

// Getting LocationManager object from System Service
// LOCATION_SERVICE
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext()
        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Getting the name of the best provider
String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

// Getting Current Location
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

if (location != null) {
    onLocationChanged(location);
}

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

// Get current location Latitude and Longitude
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
```

The problem is on the line that sets the accuracy.

When I use this I get a NullPointerException

```
// Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
```

and when I use this everything works.

```
// Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
```

oh and here are my manifest permissions

```
<permission
    android:name="com.where.common.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.where.common.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting when you make a post - there's no need for the code to be indented half way across the screen... it makes it much hard for people to read your code. I've fixed it for this post, but please fix it when asking a question in the first place next time.

Comment: Also, please show the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I found this resource on the Accuracy values that may help with determining which/how you should use them. This might let you avoid the issue you are having. It appears that setAccuracy expects the values of COURSE or FINE while there are other methods(setVerticalAccuracy, setHorizontalAccuracy, and setSpeedAccuracy) that would accept ACCURACY_LOW, MEDIUM and HIGH. However, these will work slightly differently.
[Accuracy Info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#ACCURACY_FINE)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that when you request a location with `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE`, it might take more time to get it. So when you try to do `location.getLatitude()`, you're getting a NPE.
I'd use the `Location` through the `google services` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html). Such that when a location is detected, you get a callback, then you can access its coordinates.